# Get full path of a parent of a parent of a file from relative path in bash

Tags: bash, filesystems

I'm looking for a way in bash to get full path to a parent's parent of a given file. As an example `user@host:~/grand-parent/parent $ {get-grand-parent} file` should return `/home/user/grand-parent/`.

I've tried using `dirname` multiple times, but apparently it just splits passed string and returns second last path. `dirname $(dirname parent/file)` returns `.` just like `dirname $(dirname $(dirname parent/file))`, so it only works if I pass a full path to it.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call dirname once to get the parent paht.

```
$ pwd
/opt
$ dirname mediawiki/maintenance
mediawiki
$ dirname mediawiki/maintenance/mssql/
mediawiki/maintenance
```

To get the full path giving relative path of folder or file use one of the follow

1 - realpath

```
$ realpath mediawiki/LocalSettings.php
/opt/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php
```

2 - readlink

```
$ readlink -m mediawiki/LocalSettings.php
/opt/mediawiki/LocalSettings.php
```

For a builtin solution you have to be creative

```
echo "$(cd "$(dirname "mediawiki/LocalSettings.php")"; pwd)/$(basename "mediawiki/LocalSettings.php")"
```

Comment: `dirname` doesn't return a full path. At least not on Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: Your answer doesn't give "parent of a parent" I asked in question, but it explains enough for me to solve it. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution I've come up with based on @JoaoVitorino answer.

```
$ pwd
/home/user/grand-parent/parent
$ dirname $(dirname $(realpath file))
/home/user/grand-parent
```